# Cloudflare repeated redirects error (Node JS app, NGINX for reverse proxy, Amazon EC2, SSL)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, cloudflare

I have a node application running on Amazon EC2 server on port 3000 and NGINX reverse proxy running on the same server instance and Cloudflare is my DNS. 
I am trying to attach domain name with the node application via both port 80(http) and port 443(https)

In Nginx config file if I listen on port 80 everything works fine.
Following is the config file(No problem with this as I am listening on port 80):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.in;
    location / {
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  Host       $http_host;
      proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

But if try to listen on 443 I am getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

This is the config file: (I am using Cloudflare provided private and public key)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {

    listen 443;
    server_name example.in;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/certs/cloudflare.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/certs/cloudflare.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass          http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:3000 https://example.in;
    }
  }
```

I followed this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins)
I am very new to Nginx and Cloudflare. I don't know where I am messing it up. Thanks for helping out